# Can I extract struct or public class members using a template?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Basically, I have lots of differently typed structs like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char memberA;
    int memberB;
    ...
} tStructA;
```

Is it possible to use a template to get/extract an arbitrary member from the struct? In **pseudocode**, I'm looking for something like this:

```
/*This is pseudocode!*/
template <typename STRUCT_TYPE, typename MEMBER_TYPE, membername NAME>
class cMemberExtractor
{
    public:
        MEMBER_TYPE
        extract(const STRUCT_TYPE* pStruct) const
        {
             return pStruct->NAME;
        }
};
```

The idea behind is to use the template like this:

```
/*somewhere*/
void
producer()
{
    //produce update
    tStructA* pUpdate=new tStructA;
    ...
    //send update to receivers
    emit(pUpdate);
}


/*elsewhere*/
void
consumer(const tStructA* pUpdate)
{
    //extract data
    int data=cMemberExtractor<tStructA,int,memberB>().extract(pUpdate);
    //process data
    ...
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm thinking no, because C++ doesn't have any real object metadata at runtime, but I could be unclear on what you're asking.  There also might be a horrific preprocessor hack for this.

Comment: What's wrong with `int data = pUpdate->memberB;`?

Comment: @Travis: Who was talking of runtime?

Comment: What would be the point of this? Template parameters are required to be known at compile time. This automatically means that you'll have to explicitly specify the struct type, the member type and the member name at compile time. But that achieves absolutely *nothing* over the ordinary `int data = pUpdate->memberB`. What is the point then? Your code sheds absolutely no light on this.

Comment: What's wrong with int data = pUpdate->memberB;
Basically it's lazyness and the fear of copy&paste errors:  I don't want to type this with different struct- and member names a thousand times...

Comment: As far as I can see, you are willing to type something at least two times longer 1000 times?...

Comment: @Axel: This won't help even with that memberExtractor. You should use an array.

Comment: @KennyTM: I have different struct types: tStructA, tStructB, ... with differently named members. And I need to do extractly the same stuff with different members from different structs. -> an array is not applicable here!

Comment: @Axel: Any strange idiom is not really going to help. On the contrary, with any reasonable IDE, autocompletion will help you not to miss names when writting regular `object.struct`, but I am quite sure that they will not be able to handle the more complex structure. Also, if you do make a mistake, the compiler error will probably be much more complex to interpret than in the first case.

Comment: @Axel: This scenario is indeed where member pointers could be helpful. If the members in different structs are of (related, but) different types, you'd need to templatize the code working with these pointers. That can make quite ugly code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that not with names but with member pointers:

```
template <typename C, typename M>
struct updater_t {
   typedef M C::*member_ptr_t;

   updater_t( member_ptr_t ptr, M const & new_value )
      : new_value( new_value ), ptr(ptr)
   {}
   updater_t( member_ptr_t ptr, C & original )
      : new_value( original.*ptr ), ptr(ptr)
   {}
   void operator()( C & obj ) {
      obj.*ptr = new_value;
   }
   M new_value;
   member_ptr_t ptr;
};
struct test {
   int value;
};
int main() {
   updater_t<test,int> update( &test::value, 10 );
   test object;
   update( object );

   test object2;
   updater_t<test,int> update_copy( &test::value, object );
   update_copy( object2 );
}
```

**Edit**: Moving the member pointer to a template argument as suggested by litb:

```
template <typename C, typename M, M C::* Ptr>
struct updater_t {
   updater_t( M const & new_value ) : new_value( new_value ) {}
   updater_t( member_ptr_t ptr, C & original ) : new_value( original.*Ptr ) {}
   void operator()( C & obj ) {
      obj.*ptr = new_value;
   }
   M new_value;
};
int main() {
   updater_t<test,int, &test::value> update( 10 );
   test object;
   update( object );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want (took me quite a time because I havn't seen member pointers so far)...
thank you veeery much!

Comment: Note that the main usage of this type of object is not actually the syntax (which will make some IDEs choke on autocompletion), but rather that it can be used as a brick for an undo stack or transactional changes.

Comment: It's actually possible to have it possibly more performant and nearer to the desired usage by putting the member pointer into the template like the question shows: `template <typename C, typename M, M C::*p> class updater_t { .. };`.

Comment: Right. That would reduce the memory overhead in a pointer per updater, and change the creation syntax. I thought of it, and I don't quite know why I discarded that option.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int member;
    Foo() : member() {}
};

template< typename T, typename C >
T& extract(C& obj, T C::* member)
{
    return (obj.*member);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << foo.member << '\n';
    extract(foo, &Foo::member) = 42;
    std::cout << foo.member << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

`extract(Object, &Class::Member)` returns a reference to `Member` in `Object`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted! Thank you! (Sry, David has been faster...)

Answer (score -1):

You need help from macros.

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename StructType, typename MemberType, size_t member_offset>
struct cMemberExtractor {
        MemberType extract(const StructType* pStruct) const {
             const char* member_loc = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pStruct) + member_offset;
             return *(reinterpret_cast<const MemberType*>(member_loc));
        }
};

#define M_MEMBER_EXTRACTOR(STRU, MEMTYPE, MEMNAME) \
 (cMemberExtractor<STRU,MEMTYPE,offsetof(STRU,MEMNAME)>())
...

int data = M_MEMBER_EXTRACTOR(tStructA,int,memberB).extract(pUpdate);
```

---

If your compiler supports the `typeof` operator, the `MEMTYPE` argument can be eliminated to help type safety.

```
#define M_MEMBER_EXTRACTOR(STRU, MEMNAME) \
 (cMemberExtractor<STRU,typeof(((STRU*)0)->MEMNAME),offsetof(STRU,MEMNAME)>())
...

int data = M_MEMBER_EXTRACTOR(tStructA,memberB).extract(pUpdate);
```

Comment: @KennyTM: Thx for your post, but I'd like to avoid #defines, whenever possible...